# How to Compare version of printing drivers?

Tags: windows

I have two different results for printing on 2 different computers with windows xps driver (http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/xps/viewxps.mspx). I'd like to know which version each one uses but there's no information of that kind in properties window so how to get them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use WinAudit: http://www.pxserver.com/WinAudit.htm
It'll give you that information and a lot more.